# Exchanging data between forms in a Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm exchanging data between two forms in my application using following code

Sending data from **form1** as shown below

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Form2.xaml?myparameter1={0}&myparameter2={1}", "text1", "text2"), UriKind.Relative));
```

Receiving data in **form2** as shown below

```
string receivedtext1 = null;
string receivedtext2 = null;
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("myparameter1", out receivedtext1);
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("myparameter2", out receivedtext1);
```

This is working for me with strings.

Now my question is can we exchange a byte[] between two forms in similar way as strings are exchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PhoneApplicationservice to pass data between pages in windows phone application. Here is a short example how PhoneApplicationService works, may this will help you.

```
//Before navigation
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Data"] = your byte array;
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Form2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

//On Second page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
     var data =(Cast as byte array)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Data"]
     PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Remove("Data");
    }
```